# How to Pre-Process text using only numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text classification problem where
I have a corpus of articles that relate to either cricket or afl.

I have to use just numpy to process and transform the dataset.

I want to tokenise the words so I can remove the stop words but once I do that how do I join them back into a sentence. I want to apply bag of words on the cleaned sentences.

```py
ignore_words = ["a", "the", "is", "this", "and", "if", "of", "on", "must", "be", "f", "in", "to", "have", "but", "has",
               "with", "at", "as", "his", "him", "been", "by","w","had", "for"]

sentences = [x[0].lower() for x in dataset]
labels = [x[1].lower() for x in dataset]    

cleaned_sentence = [c.replace(".", "").replace("’", "").replace("-","").replace("‘","").replace(",", "")
                    .replace("—", "").replace("”", "").replace("“", "").replace("?","").replace("$","")
                    for c in sentences]

words = []
for x in cleaned_sentence:
    x = x.split()
    for j in x:
        if j not in ignore_words:
            words.append(j)
```

Comment: `" ".join(x)` if you filter words from `x`?

Comment: it won't filter any words if I join it on x.

Comment: filter `x` first, then join. `x = [w for w in x if w not in ignore_words]`

Comment: Thank you so much Ehsan. It solved my problem.

Comment: Added answer if it helps future readers. Please feel free to accept it to close the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use join:

```
for x in cleaned_sentence:
    x = " ".join([w for w in x.split() if w not in ignore_words])
```